# ViewPager - Same background image spread out over three views

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

If I wanna use, say a picture, on a viewPager but spread each third of the picture onto the three different views of the viewPager, is this possible to do? If so, how?

Comment: I don't really use view pager, but the animation seems to slide one fragment out, just as another slides in.  Would just splitting the image into three parts, and adding them as seperate backgrounds to each fragment work?

Comment: Yes, but it's not necessarily a picture. They're three different colors and I'm trying to achieve a gradient between each of the screens. But if I do this, the startColor goes all the way to almost the middle of the view even if I define a centerColor. Is there a way to limit how far the color goes?